# Finding entries in a database with an invalid foreign key entry

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my database, `customers` and `customerAddresses`. I want to be able to find all of the customers that have an id to an address that has been deleted from the database. The customer has a FK of `addressId` that it uses to relate to the `customerAddresses` table.

```
Customer
Id    AddressId
1     1
2     3
3     5

CustomerAddresses
Id    Address
1     "Whatever"
3     "Whatever"
```

So with the above data, I want to be able to return customer 3, since they have an address Id that isn't actually present in the CustomerAddresses table.

```
  select c.Id, c.customerAddressId, ca.Id
  from Customer c
  join CustomerAddresses ca on c.customerAddressId = ca.Id
  where ca.Id is null
```

I've tried the above but that doesn't seem to work.

Usually you'd have a constraint set up to force cascading deletes, but this isn't set up in this particular case.

Comment: If you computed all of the customerAddressIds that appear in the customers table, and separately computed all of the customerAddressIds that appear in the customerAddress table, the difference would be those that you seek.

Comment: You may need to specify `left outer join` for the join.  Though if this was actually a foreign key then the delete shouldn't have been allowed in the first place.  Foreign key constraits exist specifically for that reason.

Comment: If you have a proper foreign key constraint then you don't need to do anything, because that will prevent exactly that kind of deletion you are trying to detect. To me this sounds as if you don't have a FK constraint at all.